# Errors in trying to cast to NSInteger * and NSMutableArray *

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm a newbie in obj c. So I have a simple question.
I have  a matrix of NSInteger values. It is called "curBoard". I want to update value at (x,y) coordinates with value "curStep". I have an arror "operand of type void where arithmetic..."

What am I doing wrong ?

```
[curBoard replaceObjectAtIndex:x withObject:(NSMutableArray *)[[curBoard objectAtIndex:x] replaceObjectAtIndex:y withObject:(NSInteger *)[NSNumber numberWithInt:curStep]]];
```

**Update:**

```
NSMutableArray *board; 
board = [NSMutableArray new]; 
for(NSInteger i = 0; i<boardSize; i++) { 
    NSMutableArray *row = [NSMutableArray new]; 

    for(NSInteger j = 0; j < boardSize; j++) 
        [row addObject:(NSInteger *)[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]; 
        [board addObject:row]; 
    }
```

Comment: As per your question you are having 2 dimensional matrix. How is it represented? Can you please show more code?

Comment: NSMutableArray *board;
board = [NSMutableArray new];
for(NSInteger i = 0; i<boardSize; i++)
{
NSMutableArray *row = [NSMutableArray new];

for(NSInteger j = 0; j < boardSize; j++)
[row addObject:(NSInteger *)[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];

[board addObject:row];


}

Comment: Please don't abbreviate error messages. It is always best to include the *whole* error message, not truncated halfway through. If the error as you included it in your question is all you saw, you can find all of the errors (there should be at least two or three) in their entirety in your most recent Build Log, which is in the Logs Navigator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C is basically just a bunch of object syntax strapped to C. The overall effect is something like strapping a jetpack to a horse: sometimes the two parts don't really work together very well. In this case, you're trying to go faster by telling the horse to giddy up, when you should really be opening up the throttle.

`NSMutableArray` is part of the jetpack—it's an Objective-C object and is only equipped to handle arrays of Objective-C objects. But `NSInteger` is part of the horse—it's a primitive C integer type, not a real object.*

I know `NSInteger` is capitalized like a class and has an `NS` prefix like a class, but it's really a creature of C. You can confirm this yourself—type Cmd-O in Xcode and type "NSInteger" into the Open Quickly dialog that pops up, and you'll be able to jump to its definition. In my current Mac project, that's `typedef long NSInteger;`; `long` is one of the primitive C types.

`NSNumber` exists to bridge the two. It's an object specifically designed to hold the C numeric types inside it. Since `NSNumber` is an object, `NSMutableArray` and other Objective-C things can deal with it.

But you can't just cast between `NSNumber` and `NSInteger`. `NSNumber` holds an `NSInteger` inside it, but that doesn't mean it's actually an `NSInteger` itself. If you put a sandwich in a plastic bag, you can't eat the bag.

Instead, you have to use `NSNumber`'s `+numberWithInteger:` method to construct an `NSNumber`, and `-integerValue` to get the integer back out of it. (`+numberWithInt:` and `-intValue` will usually work, but they may behave differently with very large values, depending on whether your app is running on a 32-bit or 64-bit processor.) Actually, nowadays you can say `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:foo]` as `@(foo)` instead, which is a lot shorter.**

So when you add a number, you should be saying:

```
[row addObject:@(0)];
```

And when you later want that number back, you'll want to say something like:

```
n = [[row objectAtIndex:y] integerValue];
```

The `-replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` error is a different story. `-replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` doesn't return anything at all, so you can't use it as an argument. Luckily, you don't need to in this case. `-replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` doesn't create a new array; it alters the array that's already inside `[curBoard objectAtIndex:x]`, so you don't need to do anything to `curBoard`. Instead, you can just write:

```
[[curBoard objectAtIndex:x] replaceObjectAtIndex:y withObject:@(curStep)];
```

---

* You actually used `NSInteger *`, which is slightly different. The `*` means "pointer to", so `NSInteger *` is a pointer to a primitive integer. This is sort of like `NSNumber *`, a pointer to an `NSNumber` object, so the compiler allows you to cast it.

Note that casting a pointer doesn't convert the data at the other end of the pointer; it just makes the compiler interpret the same data in a different way. If you actually tried to use the `NSInteger *` pointer to get data, you would either get garbage data or (for reasons too large to fit within this margin) crash.

In this case, though, once you've Jedi mind-tricked the compiler into thinking that value is a pointer to an `NSInteger`, you try to pass it to to `-addObject:`. `-addObject:` expects a pointer to an object, so the compiler balks at passing a pointer to an `NSInteger` instead.

** This syntax will work as long as you're using <strike>the iOS 6 SDK</strike> Xcode 4.4 or later, even if you actually run the app on an older iOS. It will also automatically use the right `+numberWithWhatever:` method for you, so you don't have to worry about picking the best one. When you're using a numeric literal like `0`, the parentheses are optional, but they're required when you use a variable or constant. Of course, you can still do it the wordy way if you want, but there's little point nowadays.

Comment: According to [the Feature Availability Index](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/), only `@YES` and `@NO` literals require the 10.8/6.0 SDK. Other number literals, along with dictionary and array literals, can be used with any SDK in Xcode 4.4 or later.

Comment: No problem, @MykytaKarpyshyn. I took a look at your profile and noticed your other questions were all in the PHP section, so I figured you were probably new to this zany hybrid type system. Don't worry, it confuses all of us at first!

Answer (score 3):

This `withObject:(NSInteger *)[NSNumber numberWithInt:curStep]]` part is what causing an issue. If you are storing as NSNumber objects, you should just use:

```
... withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:curStep]]
```

**Edit:**
From the code posted above, you should add it as:

```
[row addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
```

NSInteger is not of pointer type and you should use NSNumber itself to add to array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesn't work. I'm storing NSInteger data.

Comment: But you cant store as NSInteger. It is not a pointer type. You should store it as NSNumber.

Comment: Why not ? In the loop I initialize all the values as 0 as NSInteger ? Why can't I update with NSInteger ?

Comment: @MykytaKarpyshyn: The value you're trying to add to the array is `0` as an `int` (notice that you used `numberWithInt:`, not `numberWithInteger:`). But an NSArray object can only hold other objects, which an `int` or `NSInteger` is not. Creating an NSNumber object around the `int` is correct, but casting that to `NSInteger *` is not; the needed type is neither an `NSInteger` nor a pointer to one. The correct type is an object, and what `[NSNumber numberWithInt:]` (or `numberWithInteger:` for that matter) returns is an object, so the line would be valid and correct with no cast at all.

Comment: @MykytaKarpyshyn: As for the first line of code in your question: The error is reminding you that casting the return value of `replaceObjectAtIndex::`, of type `void`, to any other type does not make sense. `void` is the type of no value; there is no way to convert that to any type of a value. Casting a returned `void`, doubly so, because the method does not return anything and no cast will change that. I think that your cast is correct, just misplaced; move it inside the inner `replaceObject…::` message, so that you cast the result of `objectAtIndex:`, which is what I think you meant to do.